# Is it more efficient to assign an evaluation to a variable?

Tags: ruby, performance

Does Ruby remember the results of what has already been evaluated? Say I have:

```
s = "a b c d e"
```

If I did:

```
s.split.join[2] + s.split.join[3] # => "cd"
```

Would it be more or less efficient to instead do:

```
x = s.split.join
x[2] + x[3] # => "cd"
```

My thinking is that if I didn't assign `s.split.join` to a variable, then every time I use that value, Ruby would have to evaluate `s.split.join`. If `s.split.join` was called many times, that seems more costly than just checking the value of a single variable.

Comment: Yes, that is basically what local variables are for. Ruby does not cache anything.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ your example is better written as `s = "a b c d e"; s.split[2..3].join` or `s.split.join[2..3]`.

Comment: haha... thanks for the sidenote. Yeah, I just arbitrarily picked two elements, which happened to be consecutive and expressible as a range xD

Comment: It's very easy to test whether Ruby caches the evaluation of expressions automatically: since `puts` *always* returns `nil`, Ruby would be allowed to cache any call to `puts`, and thus it would be impossible to print anything in Ruby, if that were true. `puts 'Hello'; puts 'World'` would print only `Hello`, because `puts 'World'` has the same value as `puts 'Hello'` and thus would be never evaluated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything not set to a local variable will be reevaluated, so in your case it would be more efficient to set a local variable.